# How do I write a script to reboot a list of servers, but will EXCLUDE servers I don't want rebooted?

Tags: powershell

Being new to PowerShell I've been following some of the guidance in these posts to write a script for what's mentioned in the subject.

Here's the script:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Domain.txt | Restart-Computer -force | Where-Object { $._Name -notmatch "^(SERVER01)"}
```

Here's the error:

```
Restart-Computer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:40
+ ... et-Content -Path C:\temp\Domain.txt | Restart-Computer -force | Where ...
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:PSObject) [Restart-Computer], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartComputerCommand
```

For reference, the DOMAIN.txt has a list of servers that will periodically change so I want to skip certain servers should they end up on the list.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means you have an empty line on your text file, you can filter the lines using `.Where(..)` method and exclude empty or white space lines with the help of `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(..)` method. I have changed `-notmach` for the containment operator `-notin`.

**Note, `-notin` looks for an exact match within the collection `$hostsToExclude`.**

```
$hostToExclude = 'server1', 'server2'
(Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Domain.txt).Where({
    -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) -and $_ -notin $hostToExclude
}) | Restart-Computer -Force
```

It's worth noting that, on your snippet, you're restarting the hosts **before** filtering the collection. *`Get-Content` should be followed by `Where-Object`*.

Comment: Thank you for responding. It's greatly appreciated. I'll test this and get back to you (all).